# C++11 range based loop: How does it really work

Tags: c++, c++11

I know how this loop works, and how I can use it in practical problems. But I want to know what is happening under the hood.
I thought that this loop was similar to a regular `for` loop in which for example

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++){
    // instructions
}
```

Variable `i` is initialized only once, so I thought that this was the same for range based loops. But if I for example write this code:

```
for(const int x : vec) {
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

The compiler lets me to do this, but I don't understand how this is possible. If variable `x` is `const`, how come in every iteration the `x` value is different?

Comment: FYI it's closer to `for (auto iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)`

Answer (score 18):

Every iteration of the loop creates a local variable `x` and initializes it to the next element of `vec`. When the loop iteration ends, `x` goes out of scope. A single `x` is never modified.

See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) for the precise semantics.

Answer (score 3):

The range-based for-loop is indeed somewhat different than the classical for-loop in this regard. The declaration you provide (`const int x`) is declared for **every iteration separately**, in contrast to classical for-loops.

To be more precise:

```
for (const int x : vec) {
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

is just a shorthand for (and simply replaced with) the following "classical iterator loop":

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(), e = vec.end(); it != e; ++it) { 
    const int x = *it; 
    cout << x << endl; 
}
```

(except that `it` and `e` are not available in the body; also `vec` is actually "saved" in a separate variable; but let's not focus on unimportant details here; the exact definition of range-based for loop can be looked up [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for))

Note that `const int x` is declared and initialized to `*it` inside the loop body! So it is initialized in every *iteration*, rather than *changed*.

Answer (score 2):

For unterstanding purpose you can think of it as if the compiler is replacing `for (auto x: y) {...}` with `for (auto i = begin(y), end = end(y); i != end; ++i) { auto x = *i; {...} }`.

For std::vector `begin(y)`/`end(y)` will resolve (via the [adl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)) to `std::begin(y)`/`std::end(y)` versions that would call `y.begin()`/`y.end()` respectively.

Comment: more or less. For understanding it's perfect, but you should at least tell that the syntax is a little more complicated in reality

Comment: That's not quite accurate. Imagine `y` is `make_temporary()`.

Comment: `i != end`, not `i < end`.

Comment: @leemes: I've found it useful to be precise when describing C++, since seemingly unimportant details can become important when you least expect it.