# Is there a way of iterating through a C++ array without needing to know the end address from the start?

Tags: c++, arrays

Whenever I iterate over a C++ array by pointer arithmetics (i.e. not with Java-style incrementing of an index), I first get the address of the last element in the array and then iterate as long as the current address is not the last address:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int* lastAddress = values + size(values);

    for (int *p=values; p != lastAddress; p++) {
        cout << "val: " << *p << endl;
    }
}
```

Is this the generally accepted way of doing this kind of thing?

Comment: No, the "generally accepted" way is to use C++11's range iteration, to do all of this for you. This is the legacy way of working with arrays. C++11 is almost ten years old, and offers more convenient ways of doing many things of this nature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++11 range based loop: How does it really work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556196/c11-range-based-loop-how-does-it-really-work)

Comment: for (auto p = begin(values); p != end(values); ++p) , the for loop can be replaced like this too.

Comment: I would recommend `<` rather than `!=` as a general rule.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that keeps using pointers, that's why accept `std::begin` and `std::end`` approach.

Comment: Guys, don't answer in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: @TMOTTM `std::begin` / `std::end` don't return pointers. They return *iterators*.

Comment: @Den-Jason IMHO there are no advantages to using `<` rather than `!=`, but there are some extra failure scenarios. So my recommendation would be the opposite. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6673775/5910058

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- I agree that `!=` is the right choice for iterators. But `<` in ordinary iteration (e.g., over a range of numeric values) is a habit that many of us have developed; it can save things in more complex situations where, for example, the loop control variable might be incremented inside the loop. Using `<` avoids an off-by-one error that `!=` can fall into. So it's not totally without advantages.

Comment: When you've worked with embedded systems and by some quirkiness a variable becomes corrupted, you learn to use `<` to cater for weird failure scenarios.  But yes you need to be certain you're not comparing signed against unsigned ;)  Thanks for the link Jesper

Comment: @Den-Jason "by some quirkiness a variable becomes corrupted, you learn to use < to cater for weird failure scenarios" - In that situation, the solution is *not* to try to carry on with the program in a broken state. The correct solution is to crash as soon as possible and then use the crash dump to *fix* the "quirkiness".

Comment: @JesperJuhl that's fine for desktop software, not fine for e.g. a flight control or engine management system, which would need to indicate a fault flag and continue with a failure-back-up mode.  I've experienced SRAM failures before, where a not-equals check in a loop would have stalled the system for several hours.  Also, a faulty not-equals check to exit a loop does not indicate a fault, it simply stalls.  A less than condition, followed by a check for the expected terminal value, does.

Comment: @Den-Jason Are you saying that you are fine with a plane continuing operations with its engine control program being in some undefined/invalid state?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am fine with any system that can cope with failure without stopping with "computer says no".  That's why there are failure-back-up-modes in safety critical systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the generally accepted way of doing this kind of thing?

No, it isn't. You shouldn't do hand made pointer arithmetics for determining *start* and *end* of a container. That's what [`std::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) are for:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for (auto p = std::begin(values); p != std::end(values); p++) {
        cout << "val: " << *p << endl;
    }
}
```

As a short form you can use a [range based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), which uses the same mechanism under the hood:

```
for(auto value : values) {
    cout << "val: " << value << endl;
};
```

---

Please note, that this only works with arrays declared locally with a well known size (`sizeof()`).

If you get such array definitions passed to a function, you still also need to pass the size:

```
 foo(int values[], size_t size) {
      for(auto val = std::begin(values); p != std::begin(values) + size; ++p) {
          // ...
      }
 }
```

The standard accepted way is to ditch raw arrays at all, in favor of using [`std::array<T,N>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for arrays of known size, or [`std::vector<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for arrays of unknown size.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a range based `for` loop. Like so:

```
for (const auto val : values) {
    std::cout << "Val: " << val << '\n';
}
```

Note the use of `\n` rather than `std::endl`. `std::endl` implies a `std::flush` of the stream and you probably don't need that after every line. You can do one after the loop if needed.

Comment: Note: this assumes that `values` is `std::array` or `std::vector`, not a simple C array as in question. But it is in general not a good idea to use simple C arrays in C++.

Comment: @Wolfram works for C arrays too. https://godbolt.org/z/rq3jxb

Comment: @Wolfram Nope. Native arrays are fine.

Comment: Better improve and maybe drop an explanatory note. As you did for the abominable using namespace, though [dropping a note would be nice](/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Native arrays are "fine", but `std::array` is less prone to mistakes and with them you can do everything you can do with native arrays.

Comment: @Wolfram `std::array` misses sizing from the initializer, or declaring an extern one without knowing the size. Also, it needs an extra-include. Still, being first-class and allowing zero-size can be important too.

Comment: @Deduplicator in C++17 this is fine `std::array a = { 1, 2, 3 };` due to the addition of deduction guides.

Comment: @Wolfram While it's true that `std::array` can often be preferred to C arrays, that has nothing to do with anything in the question, for which ranged-based for, `std::begin` and `std::end` are all perfectly fine as-is. The dimension is part of the type, and that's how they work. :)