# Why does the range for loop iterator in C++ start at 1 and not 0?

Tags: c++, for-loop

In C++ why does the **range-for-loop** iterate starting at 1 and not at 0? In this example you would expect it to iterate through the numbers just fine however it hits an out of bounds error because i starts at 1 and ends at the size of vector.

```
vector<int> numbers2 = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
cout << numbers2.size() << '\n';

for (int i : numbers2) {
    cout << numbers2[i] << endl;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

To correctly cout the result it has to be re-written with

```
cout << numbers2[i - 1] << endl;
```

Comment: `i` is an element of the container, not the index. Try `vector<int> numbers2 = { 2,1,0,4,3 };`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++11 range based loop: How does it really work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556196/c11-range-based-loop-how-does-it-really-work)

Answer (score 5):

The range-based for loop loops through the values of the vector, there is no index. You are looping through `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` vector and `i` is each of those values throughout the iterations not the index.